# Why setattribute with hidden value is not hiding the logo?

Tags: g1ant

I had tried both values `invisible` and `hidden` but no change is observed in the logo.

Code:

```
    selenium.open chrome url duckduckgo.com
    delay 2
    selenium.setattribute class value invisible search logo_homepage by class
```

This is the image:

[image]

Comment: Corrected image url formatting.

Comment: Please insert your code because it is impossible to help you with that little information.